# exists? Ruby Postgresql Active Record Validation with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I Want, compare if this two params exists on database on same register id.

Example:

**Data.all return this.**

```
phone_number | adress
12345678     | route 66
```

On check if below return true for all params.

**My If with active record :**

```
 if Data.exists?(phone_number: "#{params["phone_number"]}", adress: "#{params["adress"]}")
   puts "true, it's registered"

 else
  puts "false not, registered."
  Data.create!(phone_number: "#{params["phone_number"]}", adress: "#{params["adress"]}")

 end
```

**if above return false for new select from two params**

**example:**

**Data.all return this.**

```
phone_number | adress
95654152   | route 67
```

Create register a new register with params, and not duplicate.

Can you help me? as I wrote it, it is validating only 1 condition, not the 2 parameters.

Comment: The phone_number and address you show in the first `Data.all` and the second are different, though

Comment: Sure, if params on condition check, is different from table data, insert on data else, only compare two params and not insert.

Comment: can you show a reproducible example of how it's not working? There is nothing obvious that is wrong with your code, so be sure to check the exact values you are passing as arguments to `.exists?` and compare them to the database values.

Comment: when I execute the original code, it compares only 1 value with that getting 2 values ​​ends up creating a new record because when comparing if the first value exists and the second one doesn't exist it creates, I'm trying to validate only if the 2 values ​​don't exist he must create the new record.

Answer (score 1):

Use active record `#find_or_create_by`. you can check the documentation here https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

```
Data.find_or_create_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number], adress: params[:adress])
```

Comment: You don't need string interpolation. And apidock is not the official documention.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution might be to use [`ActiveRecord#find_or_create_by`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by) method which returns an existing record or generate a new one if it does not exist yet:

```
Data.find_or_create_by(phone_number: params["phone_number"], adress: params["adress"])
```

Note there is no need to use string interpolation (`"#{ ... }"`) in this case. Or even shorter:

```
Data.find_or_create_by(params.permit(:phone_number, :adress))
```

But when you really need to make sure that there will never be to identical records in the database then you should ensure that in the model and the database too.

I suggest adding an [`uniqueness` validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) to the model

```
# in app/models/data.rb
validates :phone_number, uniqueness: { scope: :adress, case_sensitive: false }
```

*and* a [unique index](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index) to the database

```
add_index :datas, [:phone_number, :adress], unique: true
```

The combination of validation *and* the index ensures that you can't end up with duplicates in the database even if you forget using `find_or_create` in another controller or import data into the database through another channel.

Comment: A more elegant way is `Data.find_or_create_by(params.slice(:phone_number, :adress))`. Copying hash keys to a new hash manually is just silly in Ruby.

Comment: Hi @max, IMHO `find_or_create_by` expects the params to be permitted and raises an error when unpermitted params passed in. Therefore I think `permit` is the better option than `slice` in this case. Why would you prefer `slice` over `permit`?

Comment: Yeah permit is a better choice.